# Having trouble with using add_rewrite_rule and pagination

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

We have a section on the site, such as:

```
www.example.com/for-sale/category-name/
```

`for-sale` is a WP page, however `category-name` is dynamic and is what I wrote the below rewrite rule for.

```
add_rewrite_rule('for-sale\/([a-z-]+)\/?$', 'index.php?pagename=for-sale&search_slug=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

However, problems arise when the user needs to use the `page` query var, if I try going to:

```
www.example.com/for-sale/category-name/?page=2
```

it get's rewritten to:

```
www.example.com/for-sale/2/
```

So completely strips out the category slug.

Is there a way I can get this to work?

...or preferably I would like to be able to use something like this:

```
www.example.com/for-sale/category-name/2/
```

So I tried adding this additional rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('for-sale\/([a-z-]+)\/([0-9])+\/?$', 'index.php?pagename=for-sale&search_slug=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

..but again, it redirected back to:

```
www.example.com/for-sale/2/
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Your rewrite rules are good, but the redirect happens because WordPress applies canonical redirect via its [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) function which is hooked to `template_redirect`.

And you can *cancel the redirect* via the `parse_request` action, like so, where we check if the matched rewrite rule is the one you set when you call `add_rewrite_rule()` and if it is, then cancel the redirect by "unhooking" `redirect_canonical()` from the `template_redirect` action:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', function( $wp ){
    if ( 'for-sale\/([a-z-]+)\/([0-9])+\/?$' === $wp->matched_rule ) {
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But wouldn't that then allow these pages to be accessed with and without `www` for example?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes you're correct.. Please ignore my previous comment. :p I'll update the answer later.

Comment: Actually.. no. I've confirmed that even if I *do not* cancel the (canonical) redirect, if I visit `http://example.com/for-sale/foo/2/`, I would end up at `http://example.com/for-sale/2/`. Similarly, if I visit `http://www.example.com/for-sale/foo/2/`, I would end up at `http://www.example.com/for-sale/2/`. So I think if you want to force redirect to `www` or non-`www`, you can check [this](https://tribulant.com/docs/hosting-domains/hosting/9867/redirecting-to-www-or-non-www/) - i.e. use a "real" *htaccess* rule or the cPanel method. And have you already tried the code in the answer?

Comment: Hey Sally, the code worked well with regards to what I wanted it to do, but I was unable to test the `www` issue since I am only on local right now; but yes, if I didn't implement your code then I get the same results as you experienced.

Comment: So since the answer does help, would you mind upvoting it?.. As with the `www` issue, you can post a new question, if it actually happens on your/a production site. But I would be happy to help you with that, via this question.

Comment: Ok, no problems, thanks Sally :)